# c conversion from uint64 to float64_IEEE?

Tags: c++, c, linux, floating-point, type-conversion

SERVER CODE :

```
s64 interrupt;
```

the above is the kernel code and I am reading the above value by user application as shown below.

user code :

```
uint64 measurements [17];
uint64 Latency; 
fscanf (fp, "%u", Latency);  // I am reading the interrupt from server code using fscanf
measurements[17] = Latency;
```

but finally I want to send the measurement [17] in the FLOAT64_IEEE format to the client side.
how to do that conversion ??
could someone please help me ??

Comment: Your question aside, for the array `uint64 measurements [17]`, `measurements[17]` is invalid.

Comment: thats a typing mistake.

Comment: @user3603553 You might want to correct it...

Comment: Your code doesn't really show what you are trying to do very well. `%u` reads a value of type `unsigned int`, which in most places isn't an `uint64` (if we assume uint64 is a 64-bit unsigned integer - anything else would be rather daft)

Comment: Officially, this other question [How to solve this C error in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391123/how-to-solve-this-c-error-in-eclipse) is asked by a different user.  But it is likely that it is either the same person with two accounts or two people doing the same homework — the access to `measurements[17]` when the array is defined as `SomeType measurements[17];` sure looks systematic.

Answer (score 2):

The basic method for converting a 64-bit integer to a `double` is

```
uint64 x = 12345132091298;
double d = x;
```

However, this assumes that the value of `x` is less than 2<sup>53</sup> as an integer value, OR that you don't mind losing the bottom bits. In other words, something like this:

```
uint64 x1 = 1 << 53;
uint64 x2 = x + 1;
double d1 = x1;
double d2 = x2;

cout << d2 - d1 << endl;
```

will result in zero (assuming compiler isn't "clever" and calculates the result as a constant before doing `d2-d1`).

I personally wouldn't convert to floating point on the "client" - the "later" you process your raw data (at least if you are (risking) losing data), the better, assuming there isn't a need to reduce the data (and in this case, it's converting 64-bits to 64-bits).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the IEEE 754 standard, you should implement your own routines to convert the value into that format if your code is intended to be portable.

If portability isn't a requirement and both architectures are the same (your machine and client machine) and both use a IEEE 754 compliant FPU, you can just cast that value to float and then transmit it to the client.

Hope this gives you some clues for further research.

Edit #1 (in reply to comment):

See [here](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8281/10w/notes/100_ieee754_conversions.txt).

Comment: could you please give me a small example ??